# Clear NgbModal State in Angular and Ng-Bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, ng-bootstrap

How can i clear the modal after i successfully updated? I'm showing the errors on the modal when there is an error updating. I'm just doing the `form.reset` and `this.modalReference.close()` after successfully updating. I'm wondering how to clear the state so that when i open the modal again, the error won't be there anymore.

> component.ts

```
updateUser() {....
    if (result.value) {
              ......subscribe(() => {
                  form.reset();
                  this.modalReference.close();
              }, err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.errors = err.error;
              });
            }
}
```

> component.html

```
<app-error [errors]="errors"></app-error>
<tr>.....
```

> error.component.ts

```
export class ErrorsComponent {
      formattedErrors: Array<string> = [];

      @Input()
      set errors(errorList: Errors) {
        this.formattedErrors = [];

        if (errorList.errors) {
          for (const field of Object.keys(errorList.errors)) {
            this.formattedErrors.push(`${field} ${errorList.errors[field]}`);
          }
        }
      };

      get errorList() { return this.formattedErrors; }

    }
```

Comment: So, now errors stay? Could you please show the place where you use `ErrorsComponent` and what you pass into the input there?

Comment: Are you using Reactive form or template drive form?

Comment: @AmirArbabian. Hi! I updated my question. Pls check again.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz. . Hi! I updated my question. Pls check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer.

Add this code to the opening of the edit modal function

```
this.errors = {};
```

Comment: Is it the answer, why?

Comment: @Alex. It clears out the errors when opening of the modal edit fucntion

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistaken @Input decorators. @Input decorators are used for taking data/input from the parent component. That's it.

```
// child.component.ts

@Input()
errors: string[];

// parent.component.ts
<child [errors]="my error varialbe in parent component"></child>
```

You check [this stackblitz basic example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8vhrq)